# Closure might outlive current function even though it is joined

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = 5;

    std::thread::spawn(|| { // closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `foo`, which is owned by the current function
        println!("{}", foo);
    })
    .join()
    .unwrap();
}
```

Moving the value is not an option since it have to make multiple threads

The situation in my code is a bit more complicated, but I still need threads and I ended up moving and Arc into it instead of just a reference

Here is a link to the line in the project, but you don't have to read it: https://github.com/Antosser/web-crawler/blob/5d23ffa7ed64c772080c7be08a26bda575028c7c/src/main.rs#L291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not know it is joined. It does not apply any special analysis to see if threads are joined.

However, if you join your threads, you can use [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) to access variables:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = 5;

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            println!("{}", foo);
        });
        // Thread implicitly joined here.
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll accept as soon as I can